# vnc starts x windows but not window manager

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I am trying to remote desktop by using VNC through a tunnel.  Could someone offer advice?

I am currently seeing only a grey screen when access my computer remotely via vnc.  I am able to open windows on it from the command line, but not to manage them with my mouse (e.g. to minimize, move them, etc.).  It is like I have X running, but no window manager.

I am starting vncserver with the command:

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -dpi 96
```

(I have tried other variants, like vncserver :1 alone, or -depth 32).

I'm running 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
I use xfce for my window manager

I have tried a wide range of xstartup files.  Here is it what it looks like right now, but you can see I've been wandering around looking for the right settings... so far no luck.

```
#!/bin/bash

#xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
# Add the following line to ensure you alwayus haver an xterm available
#( while true ; do xterm ; done ) &
#exec /usr/bin/gnome-session
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
#[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
# xsetroot -solid grey
#vncconfig -iconic &
#xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
exec startxfce4
#twm &
#if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ; then
#       eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax –exit-with-session`
#       echo "D-BUS per-session daemon address is: \
#       $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"
#fi
#exec  gnome-session
```

Here is my (redacted) log file:

```
24/08/19 21:57:25 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
24/08/19 21:57:25 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
24/08/19 21:57:25 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
24/08/19 21:57:25 All Rights Reserved.
24/08/19 21:57:25 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
24/08/19 21:57:25 Desktop name 'X' (niobiumnitride:1)
24/08/19 21:57:25 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
24/08/19 21:57:25 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1

24/08/19 21:57:33 Got connection from client XX.XX.XX.XX
24/08/19 21:57:33 Using protocol version 3.8
24/08/19 21:57:33 Full-control authentication passed by XX.XX.XX.XX
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
24/08/19 21:57:33 Using zlib encoding for client XX.XX.XX.XX
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
24/08/19 21:57:33 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 18.25.10.197
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
24/08/19 21:57:33 Pixel format for client XX.XX.XX.XX:
24/08/19 21:57:33   8 bpp, depth 6
24/08/19 21:57:33   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
24/08/19 21:57:33 Using raw encoding for client 18.25.10.197
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
24/08/19 21:57:33 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 18.25.10.197
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
24/08/19 21:57:33 Using zlib encoding for client XX.XX.XX.XX
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
24/08/19 21:57:33 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 18.25.10.197
24/08/19 21:57:33 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
24/08/19 21:57:33 Pixel format for client XX.XX.XX.XX:
24/08/19 21:57:33   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
24/08/19 21:57:33   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
24/08/19 21:57:33   no translation needed
24/08/19 21:57:38 Client 18.25.10.197 gone
24/08/19 21:57:38 Statistics:
24/08/19 21:57:38   key events received 0, pointer events 600
24/08/19 21:57:38   framebuffer updates 3, rectangles 132, bytes 46979
24/08/19 21:57:38     cursor shape updates 3, bytes 1668
24/08/19 21:57:38     raw rectangles 1, bytes 17292
24/08/19 21:57:38     zlib rectangles 128, bytes 28019
24/08/19 21:57:38   raw bytes equivalent 10385316, compression ratio 229.200768
```

Comment: */usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1* are you sure the server invocation you are connecting to reflects the latest `xstartup`? have you tried starting vncserver on a different display - or explicitly killing `:1` first?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I did try `vncserver -kill :1` first.  I find that whenever I have the `exec startxfce4` or equivalent `startxfce4 &` in my xstartup file, I get that error in the log file.  Interestingly, if I comment out the `startxfce4` line in the startup file, I don't get that line, but I get exactly the same behavior (i.e. I see the grey screen without the window manager).